# Conditional CSS targeting Windows 7

Tags: css, conditional-statements, google-font-api

I can find numerous discussions like this on the web however I cannot find anyone to particulary target my problem:

I use Google Webfonts for a site. On all platforms except Windows 7 the fonts look good. But on Windows 7 I need to adjust the font weight for some of the font versions. I can successfully use a conditional statement for IE 9, but how do I actually target FF and Chrome in Windows 7 only? The font rendering in Win XP (IE 8 and below, and also FF, Chrome) is perfect, and also Mac OS is fine (FF, Safari, Chrome).

I found many hacks but none that changes CSS for a specific windows version unregarding browser...???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you wanna make it purely through CSS?

Comment: Well of course the problem might also happen on Windows Vista... (but who uses that?) :)

Comment: You'll need Javascript to get the Operating System I'm afraid :(

Comment: @jtheman Report the problem to Google aswell, http://www.google.com/webfonts#AboutPlace:about (click feedback) so the problem can be fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'll going for a JS solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done without JavaScript. Specifically, you need to check `navigator.userAgent`'s value. If it contains `NT 6.1`, then it means the client is running Windows 7. `NT 6.0` is for Windows Vista, and `NT 5.1` is Windows XP. There is no way to do this using pure CSS, unfortunately.

A sample:

```
var usAg = navigator.userAgent;
if(usAg.indexOf("NT 6.1") != -1) {
    //Windows 7, apply styles here, for instance:
    var el = document.getElementById("your_id");
    el.style.fontWeight = "700";
}
```

I hope that helped!

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use Javascript to detect Windows 7. Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 6.1') > 0)
      document.head.innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/css" />'
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is closest to how I solved it! And first to send a solution!

Comment: @Abody97 Sorry I'm new to this and I didn´t even know where to find the "edit history" but Abrahams answer seemed to be posted before Yours, but of course, You are right... Thanks anyway, no hard feelings! :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the script http://cssuseragent.org/.

Here is how you would detect [Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832.aspx) with cssua.js:

```
if (cssua.ua.windows_nt === "6.1") {
    /* target Win 7 and Win 2008 R2 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Using the NT version of windows you can target the CSS.

Comment: Yes I seen that but it seemed more tricky to get just Windows 7 (and Vista) not just Windows platform?

Comment: Just check if the appVersion or useragent contains : "Windows NT 6.1" which is Windows 7. All NT versions for windows can be found on : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for fast answers! As I had jQuery installed this is how I solved it:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 6.1') > 0)
   {
        $('body').css({'font-weight':'300'});   
   }
});
```

Comment: Great! The clearest solution for my font rendering problem in Windows 7. Thanks!